# How to declare and set a variable equal to a list of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Good morning everyone! I am trying to write a Query that accepts a list of zip codes as a variable, and then queries for values in that set. Everything seems to be working fine, except the variable which I have placed my list values into.

I have never tried using a `varchar` value to represent a list of values, so if it's not possible or if there is a better way, please let me know.

here is the code so far:

```
DECLARE @trade_firm VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @zip_list VARCHAR(255)
---------------------------------
SET @trade_firm = '0016986'
SET @zip_list = '44654,15219,15219,15219' --this is my list of zip codes
---------------------------------

SELECT oad.POSTAL_CODE_1,
      o.CHANNEL
FROM dbo.OFFICE AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ALIAS AS oa
    ON o.OFFICE_ID = oa.OFFICE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS AS oad
    ON o.ADDRESS_1_ID = oad.OFFICE_ADDRESS_ID
WHERE oa.TRADE_FIRM = @trade_firm
AND o.CHANNEL != (  SELECT f.channel
                FROM dbo.FIRM AS f
                    INNER JOIN dbo.FIRM_ALIAS AS fa
                    ON f.FIRM_ID = fa.FIRM_ID
                WHERE fa.trade_firm = @trade_firm)--will return the channel of the main firm
AND oad.POSTAL_CODE_1 NOT IN @zip_list --this is the variable as I currently have it, broken
```

Comment: Variables don't work like that. You have to handle this one of two ways. Either use dynamic sql or split the delimited string. I would chose to split the string. There are a number of ways out on the internet you will find. However most of them use a loop or xml. These are both very slow. Check out this article which explains how to do this using a tally table. It is super fast. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Couldn't you put them in a table variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE @trade_firm VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @zip_list VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @tbl_zip_list TABLE (zip_list VARCHAR(10))
---------------------------------
SET @trade_firm = '0016986'
SET @zip_list = '44654,15219,15219,15219' --this is my list of zip codes
---------------------------------

SET @zip_list = @zip_list + ','  --Add trailing ',' for closing the loop
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) > 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @tbl_zip_list
       SELECT SUBSTRING(@zip_list, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) - 1)

       SET @zip_list = SUBSTRING(@zip_list, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) + 1, LEN(@zip_list))
    END
SELECT *
FROM @tbl_zip_list

SELECT oad.POSTAL_CODE_1,
      o.CHANNEL
FROM dbo.OFFICE AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ALIAS AS oa
    ON o.OFFICE_ID = oa.OFFICE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS AS oad
    ON o.ADDRESS_1_ID = oad.OFFICE_ADDRESS_ID
WHERE oa.TRADE_FIRM = @trade_firm
  AND o.CHANNEL != (    SELECT f.channel
                    FROM dbo.FIRM AS f
                        INNER JOIN dbo.FIRM_ALIAS AS fa
                        ON f.FIRM_ID = fa.FIRM_ID
                    WHERE fa.trade_firm = @trade_firm)--will return the channel of the main firm
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM @tbl_zip_list AS ni
               WHERE n1.zip_list = oad.POSTAL_CODE_1) --this is the variable as I currently have it, broken
```

Comment: Looping to split a string will work but it is horribly slow!!! See the article I suggested in the comments of the OP.

Comment: Yes I know and I up voted it as I used the same method in my projects. However at times creating objects may not be possible on a client server so this can be used as a Option-2. Also the performance hit would not be that bad if the number of records are few.

Comment: This is great stuff, thanks for your help! I will study the code and learn to use table variables in the future for situations like this. P.S., I do not have write access to the server, which is why this method works best for me, I can't create objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you need to convert your string variable into table variable in order to be used with `IN` keyword.

One solution would be to pass a table valued parameter from your application logic. That parameter could be an array like object. Refer to [Using Table-Valued Parameters Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).

If the above is not possible one of the techniques I use is also described in the above article that is to split the comma seperated list of values into table variable.

```
declare @trade_firm varchar(20)
declare @zip_list varchar(255)
---------------------------------
set @trade_firm = '0016986'
set @zip_list = '44654,15219,15219,15219' --this is my list of zip codes

--DECLARE TABLE VARIABLE
DECLARE @ziplist_table table(
  zipcode varchar(10)
)

--TAKSE COMA SEPERATED LIST OF CODES AN INSERTS TO TABLE VARIABLE FOR LATER USE
DECLARE @pos int, @nextpos int, @valuelen int
SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1
WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @zip_list, @pos + 1)
            SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@zip_list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @ziplist_table (zipcode)
         VALUES (substring(@zip_list, @pos + 1, @valuelen))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
```

Now you can use the table variable in the `WHERE` clause like this

```
WHERE oad.POSTAL_CODE_1 not in (SELECT zipcode FROM @zip_list)
```

Comment: There is no need to use a loop here. It is horribly inefficient. See the article I referenced in the comments on the original post.

Comment: Another (better) solution would be to pass a table valued parameter from the application logic if it is supported.

Comment: Agreed a table valued parameter would work quite well in this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to split comma strings using one of the techniques found [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) ... my favorite is the Numbers table (or using a CTE, code found [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/) - but performance on a CTE can be poor, as Sean Lange pointed out in the comments).

Plugging those in to your specific code, and using the CTE in lieu of an actual Numbers table, I come up with something like this:

```
declare @trade_firm varchar(20)
declare @zip_list varchar(255)
---------------------------------
set @trade_firm = '0016986'
set @zip_list = '44654,15219,15219,15219' --this is my list of zip codes
---------------------------------

--define start and end limits

Declare @start int, @end int
Select @start=1, @end=255 -- @end should equal the maximum number of characters possibe in @zip_list

;With NumberSequence( Number ) as
(
    Select @start as Number
        union all
    Select Number + 1
        from NumberSequence
        where Number < @end
)

select oad.POSTAL_CODE_1, o.CHANNEL
from dbo.OFFICE o
inner join dbo.OFFICE_ALIAS oa on o.OFFICE_ID = oa.OFFICE_ID
inner join dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS oad on o.ADDRESS_1_ID = oad.OFFICE_ADDRESS_ID
where oa.TRADE_FIRM = @trade_firm
and o.CHANNEL != 
(
select f.channel 
from dbo.FIRM f INNER JOIN dbo.FIRM_ALIAS fa on f.FIRM_ID = fa.FIRM_ID
where fa.trade_firm = @trade_firm
)--will return the channel of the main firm
and oad.POSTAL_CODE_1 not in
  (
    SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@zip_list, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list + ',', Number) - Number)
    FROM NumberSequence
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@zip_list))
        AND SUBSTRING(',' + @zip_list, Number, 1) = ','

  ) 
Option (MaxRecursion 255)-- should equal the maximum number of characters possibe in @zip_list
```

Comment: Be very careful. Using a recursive cte is horrible from a performance perspective. Take a look here to see the performance ramifications of this type of approach. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/74118/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @SeanLange.  I don't usually use this for more than a few dozen rows, and then only when I'm writing code for an environment without a Numbers table. I've updated to include your warning.

Comment: A much more efficient way to count or generate a list of numbers is a numbers or tally table. You can even create that as a zero read cte. This will create 10,000 rows instantly. WITH
 E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
 E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
 E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS 
 (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
 )
select N from cteTally

Comment: @SeanLange, that is a great piece of code - thank you for taking the time to explain and demonstrate it so clearly!  I'll be using that everywhere going forward. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I have that as the body of a view in my system. Makes things super easy. If you need more or less rows just change the cte a little bit. I can't take credit for it though. It was originally written by Jeff Moden.

Comment: @SeanLange, Good to know! Either way, thanks for correcting me and guiding the OP away from a potentially poor answer.